# How to add smooth scrolling to Scroll-To-Top function in amp

Tags: amp-html

here is amp animation scripts i use in my code and h3 tag contains target anchor  where is takes refrence of the page to scroll

```
<h3 class="target">
      <a class="target-anchor" id="top"></a>
      <amp-position-observer on="enter:hideAnim.start; exit:showAnim.start" layout="nodisplay">
      </amp-position-observer>
    </h3>
    <amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "duration": "1000ms",
           "fill": "both",
           "iterations": "1",
           "direction": "alternate",
           "animations": [
             {
               "selector": "#scrollToTopButton",
               "keyframes": [
                 { "opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible" }
               ]
             }
           ]
        }
      </script>
    </amp-animation>
    <amp-animation id="hideAnim" layout="nodisplay">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
         "duration": "1000ms",
           "fill": "both",
           "iterations": "1",
           "direction": "alternate",
           "animations": [
             {
               "selector": "#scrollToTopButton",
               "keyframes": [
                 { "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden" }
               ]
             }
           ]
       }
      </script>
    </amp-animation>
```

Comment: Please write your question clearer what you have and what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my short answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZ58fot77jw
but here is a link too: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/visual-effects/scroll_to_top/
click on demo.